# Game AI algorithm, enemy following player

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, libgdx

I'm using LigGdx to make a game, it looks like a RPG game. When enemy is in alert state, it have to follow the player, but it can move only forward, backward, left and right, and also have to divert objects when it collides, searching for the best way to reach the player, i'm newbie on game development, and my algorithm may be completely wrong, so, I really need help...

```
private void enemyInAlert(Enemy enemy, float delta) {

    detectDirection(enemy);

    enemyWalking(enemy, delta);

    if (Math.round(getDistanceXofLastPosition(enemy)) == 0 && Math.round(getDistanceYofLastPosition(enemy)) == 0) {
        enemy.setState(States.IDLE);
        lastPosition = null;
    }
}

private void detectDirection(Enemy enemy) {
    float diff = getDistanceXofLastPosition(enemy) - getDistanceYofLastPosition(enemy);
    if (diff < 0) {
        getDirectionX(enemy);
    } else if (diff > 0) {
        getDirectionY(enemy);
    }
}

private void getDirectionY(Enemy enemy) {
        int enemyY = Math.round(enemy.getY());
        int lastPositionY = Math.round(lastPosition.getY());

        if (enemyY < lastPositionY && enemy.isDirectionBlocked(Direction.FORWARD) == false) { //Enemy needs to go forward
            enemy.setDirection(Direction.FORWARD);
            enemy.blockDirection(Direction.BACKWARD);
        } else if (enemyY > lastPositionY && enemy.isDirectionBlocked(Direction.FORWARD) == false) { //Enemy needs to go backward
            enemy.setDirection(Direction.BACKWARD);
            enemy.blockDirection(Direction.FORWARD);
        } else { //Enemy needs to change direction
            if (enemy.isDirectionBlocked(Direction.LEFT) == false || enemy.isDirectionBlocked(Direction.LEFT) == false) {
                enemy.blockDirection(Direction.BACKWARD);
                enemy.blockDirection(Direction.FORWARD);
                getDirectionX(enemy);
            } else {
                sortRandomDirection(enemy);
            }
        }
    }

    private void getDirectionX(Enemy enemy) {
        int enemyX = Math.round(enemy.getX());
        int lastPositionX = Math.round(lastPosition.getX());

        if (enemyX < lastPositionX && enemy.isDirectionBlocked(Direction.RIGHT) == false) { //Enemy needs to go right 
            enemy.setDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
            enemy.blockDirection(Direction.LEFT);
        } else if (enemyX > lastPositionX && enemy.isDirectionBlocked(Direction.LEFT) == false) {
            enemy.setDirection(Direction.LEFT);
            enemy.blockDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
        } else { //Enemy needs to change direction
            if (enemy.isDirectionBlocked(Direction.FORWARD) == false && enemy.isDirectionBlocked(Direction.BACKWARD) == false) {
                enemy.blockDirection(Direction.LEFT);
                enemy.blockDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
                getDirectionY(enemy);
            } else {
                sortRandomDirection(enemy);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm accepting suggestions, I can change all the code, no mercy... Sorry for the bad English :D

Thanks!!

Edit: now, I'm trying to use A*, or something like it. :D ... my code:

```
    private void calculateRoute(Enemy enemy) {
        int lowerPath = getDistanceXofLastPosition(enemy.getBounds()) + getDistanceYofLastPosition(enemy.getBounds());

        path = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
        Rectangle finalRect = new Rectangle(enemy.getBounds());

        List<Rectangle> openList = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
        while (getDistanceXofLastPosition(finalRect) > 0 || getDistanceYofLastPosition(finalRect) > 0) {

            for (int i = -1; i < 2; i+= 1) {
                outerloop:
                for (int j = -1; j < 2; j+= 1) {

                    Rectangle temp = new Rectangle(finalRect);
                    temp.offSet(i, j);

                    if (openList.contains(temp)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if ((i == -1 && j == -1) || (i == 1 && j == -1) || (i == 0 && j == 0) || (i == 1 && j == -1) || (i == 1 && j == 1)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    for (Collider collider : colliders) {
                        if (collider.isSolid() && Utils.detectCollision(temp, collider.getBounds())) {
                            continue outerloop;
                        }
                    }
                    openList.add(temp);
                }
            }

            int lowerDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            for (Rectangle rect : openList) {
                int distance = getDistanceXofLastPosition(rect) + getDistanceYofLastPosition(rect);
                distance = distance + lowerPath;

                if (distance < lowerDistance) {
                    lowerDistance = distance;
                    finalRect = rect;
                }
            }
            path.add(new Rectangle(finalRect));
        }
}
```

but is very slow, what I can do to increase performance?

Comment: Please read each tag's wiki info on *this* site before using it here. This is a site for professional and "enthusiast" programmers, therefore [tag:rpg] is used to indicate a [programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/rpg/info) used by professional programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) .

You can easily convert your map into a graph, using each tile as a vertex, and having said vertex connected with an edge to all the other vertices close to it. The cost associated with the edge may be variable, for instance, moving i tile on a river could cost more than moving one tile in a plane.

Then you can use a path search algorithm to find the best path from one point to another. Using this algorithm will have 2 downsides :

1. It has an high computational cost
2. It always finds the optimal solution, making your bot smarter than the average player :)

If computational and storage cost are indeed a problem, you can resort to one of A*'s cousins, such as

- [IDA*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA%2a) for cheaper memory requirements, iterate over the depth of the solutions
- [SMA*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMA%2a) bounds the amount of memory the algorithm can use

Comment: But my map is not made by tiles, is it a problem? thanks for help :D

Comment: It shouldn't be : if you can define "top right left bottom", then you must have some sort of measure on the map. Pick the smallest value for it, and a square of said value can be associated to a tile. All in all, you just have to be able to build a grid on your map to use the algorithm.

Comment: Your code seems to be using a greedy approach, trying to chose the move that will minimize his distance from the hero. The problem with an approach like that is that your bot can get stuck(think what happens if he gets to face a wall). I'd rewrite it using the algorithm I suggested, or one of his cheaper cousins.

Comment: Well, I'll try to do it, but I don't know how exactly do it (I'm newbie, remember that? lol)... thanks very much, later I'll put the results here... I still have some doubts, but I don't want to be even more annoying... once more time, thanks and sorry for the English

Comment: A* works fine on tiles (think of each tile as a node in the A* graph). also, remember that in games we cheat, a lot. If it looks right, it is right, whether its correct isn't really important. for example, you could have the AI completely ignore things that the player is unable to traverse through for simplicity, or have the AI warp directly to the player is very far away.